# Java - return all cookies on hard drive

Tags: java, cookies

I am using Java 8, this is a personal project to learn more programming.

I want to display all the cookies that are displayed on my hard drive. I understand they are all in a certain folder, the profile folders. Even just displaying them encrypted or as an object would be a good start.

In order to do what I want to do, can someone recommend a library to look into or something?

this is my first post, if I am not clear, I'm sorry.

Comment: you mean browser cookies?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look a [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This question is off-topic because its just recommending a tool or library so it isn't really a good fit.

Comment: I did mean browser cookies, I did more research and found what I needed. Thank you for the link.